# Completely turn off monitor detection

Tags: windows-7, display

I really want Windows 7 to stop detecting extra monitors whenever they are connected. (My specific reason for this is explained in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/347037/dell-laptop-keeps-detecting-a-virtual-generic-non-pnp-display-device).)

How can I do this?

Comment: @Gareth, Thanks for the edit, but I dont want this question to be completely related to my problem only. Others might also want to disable monitor detection, but some other particular reason, dont you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `win + P` combination and then set the "value" to `Computer Only` probably now it's on `Extend`

Comment: No, this would only stop the monitor for now, next time it is connected, it will be detected.

Comment: @Starx - It would be fair easier to fix the problem.  As for being able to turn off the monitor detection ability, I don't think you can, would make it tough to detect new monitors.

Comment: @Ramhound, I will not disagree with your point, but I am looking for a temporary fix till I dont have my warranty transferred.