# W10, 3 Displays - how to prevent HDMI display cutting off other displays?

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi

I have a W10 machine at with 3 displays attached using:

1. HDMI
2. USB 3 > HDMI adapter
3. DVI

and two graphics card.

1. Onboard Intel HD Graphics - powers DVI & HDMI Displays
2. USB > HDMI Adapter -> powers 2nd HDMI display

Graphics card drivers are up to date and both graphics adapters report to work fine.

Now, once in a while it happens that 2 of the displays stop working out of nowhere and I have figured out that it seems the pure HDMI Display remaining 'online' and kind of blocking off the other 2 displays.

- Once I unplug the HDMI cable the other displays come back to live.
- When I connect the HDMI display with a VGA cable all 3 displays work in parallel as they should. that would be fine with me but the quality much better on HDMI.

So I am wondering what I could do to makes them work together without the VGA workaround. Did anyone have a similar problem and could give advise on how to approach this?

**EDIT:** the entire system died yesterday. So maybe the display problem was just symptom of that dying system. On the new install for now all is working fine with all 3 displays

Comment: are you using a TV as monitor? see [Why won't my taskbar display on my secondary monitor? (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/q/961665/241386)

Comment: @phuclv no, not a TV. 3 LSD displays