# Overscanning on monitor (no root access) RHEL 6

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, overscan

Is there a way to get rid of overscanning on a monitor without using non-default software or needing to have root access? This is for a computer I use at work and find the overscanning quite annoying.

The OS is RHEL 6.

Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you mean [overscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan) as for TV sets, where part of the image is shown outside the visible bounds of the screen, or overscan compensation, where the image is made smaller to make sure it's displayed completely on different TV sets? Both usually don't happen on monitors. On monitors, you can usually also adjust the image size using controls on the monitor.

Comment: overscan is controlled by the monitor and not the OS. You can just open the monitor, look for the option and turn it off [Why won't my taskbar display on my secondary monitor? (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/q/961665/241386)